# Dúvida sobre a nova versão do bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida aqui sobre a nova versão do `bootstrap` que seria a 4 atualmente estou gostando bastante vi que mudou muita coisa mais gostaria de saber se algum de vocês sabe me informa se nessa nova versão existe alguma classe que faça um elemento ser do mesmo tamanho que o outro? sei que a versão 3 não tinha ai tinha que usar um plugin `jQuery` para fazer isso que se chama [match height](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/) alguem saberia me dizer se com essa nova versão do bootstrap ja podemos fazer isso sem precisar de arquivos externos?

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma forma sim e está na documentação oficial, vc pode usar os `Cards Decks` para isso. Vale lembrar que agora isso é mais fácil de fazer pq o Grid do Bootstrap 4 a baseado no `Flex-Box`.

Link da documentação: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks

Nos **Utilitis** do Bootstrap existem várias outras classe de `Flex-Box` que vc pode usar dentro do Grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
/* estilo apenas para vc visualizar as 3 colunas em telas pequenas */
    .card-deck {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    background:silver;
    padding:1rem;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```